# Laravel Mongodb Raw mongo query with date

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I am working on laravel 5.1 and using jessenger mongodb package.
I am using raw query to fetch data but i am confused how to use date with that as currently it is returning null result.

```
 $resultSet = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('wc_mycollection')->raw(function ($collection){
            return $collection->aggregate([
                [
                    '$match'=>[
                        'created_at'=>[
                            '$gte' => Previous day midnight,
                            '$lt' => Current Time
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    '$group' => [
                        '_id' => '$some_id',

                    ]
                ]
            ]);
        });
```

what should i do?

Comment: After you are assigning date param, print the query and see if the date parameter is setting properly, if yes then try to convert that timestamp to mongo based time format. Look Here: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/shell-types/#mongo-shell-date-type

Answer (score 1):

There is a really nice date handling package in laravel called **[Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)** that you could use with your queries. If you want to get records from start of today, use Carbon's **[`startOfDay()`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/tests/Carbon/StartEndOfTest.php)** property or to get the previous date midnight, use **[`Carbon::yesterday()->endOfDay()`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/tests/Carbon/StartEndOfTest.php)**.

Joining all of this together you can construct your pipeline as:

```
$previousDayMidnight = Carbon::yesterday()->endOfDay(); // or $startOfToday = Carbon::now()->startOfDay()
$currentTime = Carbon::now();
$result = DB::collection('wc_mycollection')->raw(function($collection)
{
    return $collection->aggregate(array(
        array(
            '$match' => array(
                'created_at' => array(
                    '$gte' => $previousDayMidnight, // or $startOfToday
                    '$lt' => $currentDateTime
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => '$some_id',
                'count' => array(
                    '$sum' => 1
                )
            )
        )   
    ));
});
```

---

Another approach would be to natively use MongoDate objects, you could try

```
$start = new MongoDate(strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', '-1 days')));
$end = new MongoDate(strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
$result = DB::collection('wc_mycollection')->raw(function($collection)
    {
        return $collection->aggregate(array(
            array(
                '$match' => array(
                    'created_at' => array(
                        '$gte' => $start, 
                        '$lt' => $end
                    )
                )
            ),
            array(
                '$group' => array(
                    '_id' => '$some_id',
                    'count' => array(
                        '$sum' => 1
                    )
                )
            )   
        ));
    });
```

Comment: I am getting empty set.my collection looks like this : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e6eff42f706e30047b23c8"),
    "war_id" : 3,
    "topic_id" : 5,
    "point_id" : 7,
    "point" : 1,
    "comment_id" : "55e6efdd2f706e0d047b23ca",
    "user_id" : 11,
    "upvote_id" : 3,
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2015-09-02T12:47:48.191Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2015-09-02T12:47:48.191Z")
}

Comment: One way you can debug a pipeline that's giving you unexpected results is to run the aggregation with just the first pipeline operator. If that gives the expected result, add the next. In the answer above, you'd first try aggregating just the `$match`; if that works, add the `$group`. This can help you narrow down which operator is causing issues.

Comment: Also, to help you with debugging, just check to see if those date variables are giving you the correct dates as well as checking with your actual MongoDB dates.

Comment: The match operator is causing the issue

Comment: Can you debug the `$match` operator by changing the date variables in the range query, see if some dates match?

Comment: i dont know why but it is always giving empty set whenever i try.

Comment: Did you properly install the [**Carbon**](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#installation) library? If you can't use Carbon then you can, as an alternative, try creating the dates from `MongoDate` constructor, as shown in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this option:

```
'$match'=>[
      'created_at'=>[
             '$gte' => new Date("2016-10-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
             '$lt' => new Date("2016-11-02T00:00:00.000Z")
      ]
]
```

See, if that works.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$start = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(new \DateTime("-8 days"));
```